# When Xampp is connected, my CSS wont show up as if it isn't linked to my index.php, when it is

Tags: php, css, xampp

Ok. i have seen my website in action with the html extensionson it, Now i am attempting to upload it to my local Xampp server so that i can attach PHP to it.  So now its definitely connected because i wrote a small script to print out information that was put into a form and the script worked. the only issue is that when i run the site from my editor the CSS is applied fine just how i wanted it. but when i run it from my localhost so that the script can be ran as well i lose my CSS and none of my links seem to be clickable or connected.  I have been reviewing PHP tutorials for 3 days now and i cant seem to get my Page to come up with THE CSS and all the links connected when going thru thru the xampp localhost.

i didn't think it was necessary to post up code that i know works but if that would help anybody help me then i will gladly post it. please just let me know. this is a crisis. i need you guys, please some one be my hero!

```
 <head>
    <title> Black America Rising Web Radio </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BARwebstyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/gbtdmini.png" width= "16px" height= "16px">
</head>

<body background="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/skyBG.jpg">

    <div class="navigation">

        <nav class="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BARwebradio.php"> HOME </a></li>
                <li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BARPurpose.php"> OUR PURPOSE </a></li>              
                <li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BARSchedule.php"> SCHEDULE </a></li>
                <li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BARArchive.php"> ARCHIVE </a></li>
                <li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BAROBFNews.php"> OBF NEWS </a></li>
                <li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BARYourVoice.php"> YOUR VOICE </a></li>
                <li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\BARContact.php"> CONTACT US </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>



        <nav class="userNav">  
            <ul>
                <li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio/subscribe.php"> SUBSCRIBE </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> LOGIN </a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>


    <div class= "sliderBox">
        <div class="logo">
            <img  src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/Black-America-Rising-logo.png" alt="Logo" >
        </div> 
        <section>
            <h4>
                “What became of the Black People of Sumer?” the traveler asked the old man,<br> 
                “for ancient records show that the people of Sumer were Black.  <br>
                What happened to them?”  “Ah,” the old man sighed.<br>
                “They lost their history, so they died.”<br>
                                                           - A Sumer Legend
            </h4>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class= "wrapper">
        <div class= "contentBox">
            <div class="sideContent">
                <article>

                        <h3>About the Host - Malik Green</h3>
                        <img class= "profile" src= "C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/malikgreenProPic.jpg" alt= "Malik Green profile picture" >

                <br>Malik Green is the author of “The Black-Print - Black America's Blueprint for Achieving Wealth, Prosperity and Respect”; and the founder of the Committee to Organize the One Black Family, 
                an organization with a mission to inform, educate, inspire, and unite the Black people of America.  This organization is seriously committed to the social, spiritual, political and economic
                advancement of African Americans and Black people throughout the world. 
                <br>Malik is also the host of “Black America Rising” a bi-weekly internet radio show dedicated to the same purpose as his book and organizing committee.  
                His energy and passion for Africans is broadly displayed as he delves into the issues negatively effecting Black people.  His consistent and insistent call for unity among African Americans.  
                The show focuses on providing solutions to the myriad of social, spiritual, political and economic challenges facing Blacks in America.
                <br>As the former editor of the blog www.Insightful-Opinion.com; Malik provided political and social commentary on the current state of Black America and America as a whole. 
                Mr. Green's ultimate goal is to help forge unity and love among our people which is paramount in quest to achieve wealth, prosperity and respect here in America and throughout the world. 

                </article>
            </div>  


            <div class="content">

                <h3>Black America Rising Internet Radio Show   </h3>
                <p>
                    It’s now time for us as a people to take responsibility for our own destiny.  We must realize that the only thing that can stop us, is us!  
                    We must develop the plans, strategies, and organizational structure that will help us meet our challenges and put our people on a path
                    of prosperity never realized in America.  Hoping and waiting for the opposition to bring forth solutions and resources to our people is somewhat delusional. 
                    History is a revealer of truth.  Our history in America has been a struggle to say the least from day one. 
                    What will it take for America to respect the Black people in America?  Answer:  When we stop relying on fiery speeches,
                    protesting and denouncing injustices, relying on politics and politicians as our primary methods for the resolution of our challenges.  
                    These methods indicate weakness; we can no longer be reactive and emotional when we are challenged by the opposition. 
                     The cry for jobs, justice, equality and fairness of opportunity portrays us an inferior people, who is always hat-in-hand.  We must educate our people about our history, 
                     our forefathers and their great achievements to mankind and the creators of the first great civilization.  We must inspire our people to reclaim the greatest of our ancestors, 
                    or else continue on this most dreadful path of self-destruction.

                </p>

            </div>


        <div class="sideContent2">
            <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/184213882%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-f9gMU&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
        </div>

        </div>


    <!--I AM BUILDING THE 3 BOXES UNDERNEATH CONTAINING  NEW, SCHEDULE, AND TOP 3 ARTICLES!!! -->

    <div class= "contentTray">
        <div class="popboxLeft">

                <h5>Popular Articles</h5>
                <div class= "icons">    
                <ul>
                    <li><a href= "https://www.facebook.com/malik.green.127?ref=eyJzaWQiOiIwLjIwMzA1ODMwNTQyOTI5NDciLCJxcyI6IkpUVkNKVEl5VFdGc2FXc2xNakJIY21WbGJpVXlNaVUxUkEiLCJndiI6Ijc0NjZjMjBhYzg5ZjQ3ZDYxODVmM2E2NTE0NjFjMWIxYmFjOWE4MmQifQ"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/fbicon.jpg" alt="faceboock icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/yticon.jpg" alt="Youtube icon"><a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/twittericon.png" alt="Twitter icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/pdicon.jpg" alt="Podcast icon" width="50px" height= "50px"><a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/TIicon.jpg" alt="Tunein icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/spreakicon.jpg" alt="Spreaker icon"><a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="schedboxCenter">

                    <h5>Tune in your way!</h5>
                <div class= "icons">    
                <ul>
                    <li><a href= "https://www.facebook.com/malik.green.127?ref=eyJzaWQiOiIwLjIwMzA1ODMwNTQyOTI5NDciLCJxcyI6IkpUVkNKVEl5VFdGc2FXc2xNakJIY21WbGJpVXlNaVUxUkEiLCJndiI6Ijc0NjZjMjBhYzg5ZjQ3ZDYxODVmM2E2NTE0NjFjMWIxYmFjOWE4MmQifQ"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/fbicon.jpg" alt="faceboock icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/yticon.jpg" alt="Youtube icon"><a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/twittericon.png" alt="Twitter icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/pdicon.jpg" alt="Podcast icon" width="50px" height= "50px"><a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/TIicon.jpg" alt="Tunein icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/spreakicon.jpg" alt="Spreaker icon"><a></li>
                </div>
            </div>  


            <div class="newsboxRight">

                <h5>OBF News Highlights</h5>
                <div class= "icons">    
                <ul>
                <li><a href= "https://www.facebook.com/malik.green.127?ref=eyJzaWQiOiIwLjIwMzA1ODMwNTQyOTI5NDciLCJxcyI6IkpUVkNKVEl5VFdGc2FXc2xNakJIY21WbGJpVXlNaVUxUkEiLCJndiI6Ijc0NjZjMjBhYzg5ZjQ3ZDYxODVmM2E2NTE0NjFjMWIxYmFjOWE4MmQifQ"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/fbicon.jpg" alt="faceboock icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/yticon.jpg" alt="Youtube icon"><a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/twittericon.png" alt="Twitter icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/pdicon.jpg" alt="Podcast icon" width="50px" height= "50px"><a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/TIicon.jpg" alt="Tunein icon"><a></li>
                    <li><a href= "#"><img src="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/spreakicon.jpg" alt="Spreaker icon"><a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- IMAGES FOR THE PAGE ENDING -->



    <div id="copyright" class="footer">
            <p>&copy; 2014 Black America Rising All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Always post code. You may be overlooking something that someone else may be able to point out. If you don't post your code we have nothing to work from to try and help you.

Comment: sOK so what part of the code should i post .. i have 9 php pages including the index and  aCSS page .. thats a lot of code to post and i cant pinpoint where the problm is

Answer (score 1):

You are using an absolute path to your user documents area on your local PC.

If you have moved your files to the XAMPP directory then they no longer exist in C:/users/ you need to use relative paths.

For example

```
<li><a href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio/subscribe.php"> SUBSCRIBE </a></li>
```

Should be

```
<li><a href="subscribe.php"> SUBSCRIBE </a></li>
```

And

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="C:\Users\menta_000\Documents\internet talk show\htdocs\Barwebradio\Bar Media/gbtdmini.png" width= "16px" height= "16px">
```

Should be

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Bar Media/gbtdmini.png" width= "16px" height= "16px">
```

Comment: thanks man .. i really cant understand how i would forget that .. its works great now .... i really appreciate the help !